# PHP Error/Success Redirects

Tags: php, exception

I have a decent understanding of PHP errors (I'm not using or die() as much as I used to) but I still don't fully understand how to deliver the fatal error messages to the user in a way that isn't plain text in the upper left hand corner.

Say I have this code:

```
try {  
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=host; dbname=userDB", $username, $password); 
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE employee SET password = :newpass WHERE password = :tempPass");
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt->execute(array('tempPass' => $tempPass, 'newpass' => $newpassword));
echo'success!<br>';
echo"<a href='main_login.php'>Back</a>";

    }  
catch(PDOException $e) {  
        echo 'ERROR:   '. $e->getMessage();  
    }
```

That's all well and good, but whether it's successful or not, it's an ugly message of affirmation.

Should I be redirecting my users to a different page to deliver this message?

If so, how should I store/transport the messages to the individual page?  I don't want to have to create user_success.php, user_failure.php, user_epic_failure.php, every_other_case.php.  It's not efficient and it limits what I can do.

I've heard that storing these messages into a session error variable is a good way to do this but is it the best way to do this?  Should there be a dedicated error page and dedicated success page that just serve as templates to which I pass my messages?

I just want pretty error messages.  Is that so much to ask?

Comment: create a function that outputs pretty error messages and does an exit, then simply call yourErrorFunction('message here') where you need it .. ?

Comment: Yep, just store it into session.  On any page that might display an error, display the value from `$_SESSION` if it is set, and then unset it so subsequent pages don't show it again.

Comment: I don't really think there is a reason to be displaying errors on the page that experienced it.  Generally speaking, most of my errors will be from bad data from their databases or bad credentials or other hardware issues that they probably caused.  That means my app really isn't at fault and can't do anything.  So I feel like just shooting them off to another page is the best option.  Am I tragically misguided in thinking that?

Answer (score 0):

never display system error message to the user, this could give a potential hacker information about your system. have a generic error page that you redirect to from the catch clause if a fatal error occurs. 
for all other errors that don't cause a fatal error and stop the code executing, just continue executing your code and display an error message on top of your page if necessary.